# como usar ajax en asp.net framework mvc?

Tags: c#, ajax, mvc

Estoy utilizando java script para generar un valor que envió a un controlador de asp.net framework c# ese valor lo utilizo para hacer una consulta y si trae información retorna a una pagina especifica si no retorna a otra pagina diferente el problema es que al recibir el valor y entrar en dicha condición sea 1 o 0 no redirecciona  se queda en la misma vista donde genere el valor con js .

Como puedo hacer que el controlador reaccione al redireccionamiento con la respuesta de ajax ?

```
  public ActionResult AjaxResult(infModel pcm)//aqui recivo el valor que me envia ajax correctamente 
        {
            var valorcons = GetPackagesInfo(info);
            cons= pcm.code;           

            if (guideCode.Count == 0)
            {
      
                return RedirectToAction("Remitentes", "ReceptionPackage");/*cuando cae en esta exprecion no redirecciona y regresa a la misma vista lo mismo con las demas expresiones he igual ya se intento con result ,link,view . */
            }
  else if (guideCode[0] != null  && guideCode[0].dataRem == null && guideCode[0].dataDes == null)
            {



                return RedirectToAction("Remitentes","ReceptionPAckages");
            }
            else if (guideCode[0] != null && guideCode[0].dataRem != null && guideCode[0].dataDes == null )
            {

                

                return RedirectToAction("Destinatario", "ReceptionPAckages");
            }
            else if (guideCode[0] != null && guideCode[0].dataDes != null && guideCode[0].dataRem != null)
            {


                return RedirectToAction("DekiveryType", "Pasckages");
            }
```

Comment: El objetivo primario de ajax (al menos como yo he podido entender) es evitar la recarga de páginas completas al hacer actualizaciones de datos en el servidor y recargar parcialmente con resultados y actualizar secciones de la página desde la que se hace el llamado. **Si lo que necesitas es redirigir a otras páginas, carece de sentido el uso de ajax**. Y, posiblemente, al tratarse de una respuesta ajax, se mantiene en la página que hace la invocación. En en evento **done** del llamado debes redirigir si es lo que deseas.

Comment: Entonces cual seria la forma de pasar el valor de js a c# ?,por lo que e leido en la web sugieren  ajax .

Comment: Sugieren ajax para casos en los que **deseas mantenerte en la misma página** sin recargarla completamente, porque ahorra tiempo y es efectivo. Si necesitas que los datos enviados den paso a otras páginas, basta con hacer submit de un formulario (preferiblemente usando post) y al procesar los datos usar **location** en el head para redirigir y si falla pasar la etiqueta meta `"<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=Direccion_deseada\">\r\n"` al enviar encabezados